# get the part of an image when clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an image file loaded from my project folder my aim is to identify which part of the image is clicked is there a react package like zone js or javascript workaround to do this

my  image file

```
{Boolean(galleyItems)&& Object.values(galleyItems).includes('A350')? <img src={A350}  alt='' width="50%" height="50%"/>:<img src={B777}   alt='' width="50%" height="50%"/>}
```

here A350 and B77 are shown based on conditions form my api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's [a link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_imagemap.asp)!
Image Map
The HTML  tag defines an image map. An image map is an image with clickable areas. The areas are defined with one or more  tags.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).